Accessing to a box in Hive throws an error
So I'm trying to start my app by creating a new type "Empresario" object or by finding an existing one to access the profile of the empresario.
The empresario object has a list of "Empresa" objects, and when this list was empty, the app worked fine, until i added one object to the list, and now I recieve this error everytime i try to access to the "Empresario" box:
HiveError (HiveError: To use this list, you have to open the box "empresas" first.)
I tried to open the box empresas too, but even that line fails.
The structure of the object:
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:apiary/objetos/empresa.dart';

part 'empresario.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Empresario extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  final String id;

  @HiveField(1)
  final String? nombre;

  @HiveField(2)
  final String correo;

  @HiveField(3)
  final String password;

  @HiveField(4)
  final String? telefono;

  @HiveField(5)
  final String? foto;

  @HiveField(6)
  List<Empresa>? empresas;

  Empresario({
    this.id = '',
    this.nombre,
    required this.correo,
    required this.password,
    this.telefono,
    this.foto,
    this.empresas,
  });
}

And these are the methods where the application stops:
  Future<void> saveEmpresario(Empresario empresario) async {
    final Box<Empresario> empresarios =
        await Hive.openBox<Empresario>('empresarios');
    empresarios.add(empresario);
  }

  Future<Empresario?> findEmpresarioByCredentials(
      String correo, String password) async {
    final Box<Empresario> empresarios =
        await Hive.openBox<Empresario>('empresarios');

    final empresario = empresarios.values.firstWhereOrNull(
      (empresario) =>
          empresario.correo == correo && empresario.password == password,
    );

    return empresario;
  }

Both methods stop at final Box<Empresario> empresarios = await Hive.openBox<Empresario>('empresarios');

You need to open a box in your main.dart like this:
late Box box;

void main() async {
  await init();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

Future init() async {
  await initHive();
}

Future initHive() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  box = await Hive.openBox('box');
}

